Approximation of 1st and 2nd moment in Adam optimizer paper
So I've started working through the infamous Adam optimizer paper. There are a ton of questions on this side relating this method. Thus I will do my best not to create s replicate but I just couldn't find any answer to my issue online.
My question concerns the following passage from the paper:

The algorithm updates exponential moving averages of the gradient (mt) and the squared gradient
(vt) where the hyper-parameters β1, β2 ∈ [0, 1) control the exponential decay rates of these moving
averages. The moving averages themselves are estimates of the 1st moment (the mean) and the
2nd raw moment (the uncentered variance) of the gradient. However, these moving averages are
initialized as (vectors of) 0’s, leading to moment estimates that are biased towards zero, especially
during the initial timesteps, and especially when the decay rates are small (i.e. the βs are close to 1).
The good news is that this initialization bias can be easily counteracted, resulting in bias-corrected
estimateŝ mt and̂ vt. See section 3 for more details.

I don't understand how these moving averages are estimates of the 1st and 2nd moment. In my mind this doesn't make sense intuitively, so maybe somebody could elaborate on that.
And coupled with I also don't really get the bias correction from section 3. There they correct the difference between the expected value of the moving average and the gradient itself which in my mind hasn't got anything to do with approximating momentum with these moving averages themselves.
So further down in the paper they show that
$$ \mathbb{E}[v_t] = \mathbb{E}[(g_t)²] * (1-\beta_2²)$$
For $v_t = (1-\beta_2) * g_t² + \beta_2 * v_{t-1}.$
But in the paragraph above they aim to achieve
$$ \frac{v_t}{(1-\beta_2²)}  \approx \sum_t {(g_t)}² * f(g_t) \text{ (uncentered second moment)}$$
where $f$ describes the distribution of $g_t$.

Welcome to the site! Re: "First of all. How can this be considered a MOVING average. " It doesn't say that it's a moving average, it says that it's an exponential moving average. It may be worth consulting the relevant wikipedia page. For your other two points, it might be helpful to expand a bit on where you are confused. What would you expect the moments to look like, and how does this differ from the EMA? What do you expect the bias correction to look like, and how does this differ from how it actually looks?

Is Adam infamous? What for?

I've tried to correct my question. But I don't know whether this makes any sense. So I would appreciate some feedback.
